# Disable a textbox inside Repeater control when any of the DropDownList values also inside Repeater, is selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have a textbox and dropdownlist controls inside a repeater control.

The textbox is called txt_watersizes and the dropdownlist is called ddlWater.

The dropdownlist currently has three values although this could increase. The dropdownlist values are dynamically populated from the database.

To keep things simple, I have manually added values to the dropdownlist.

This is our back office feature and is handled only by an admin.

The way it works is that if an admin wishes to create a record, he selects a value from the dropdownlist. If the value he wishes to select is not on the dropdown, he enters the value into the textbox. The value is then added to the lookup table storing the dropdownlist values while the ID of or value of the dropdownlist is added to the main table. This works great.

Now, we have two issues.

1, we do not want the admin to mistakenly select a value from the dropdown and at the same time, enter the value in the textbox.

As a result, I came up with a JavaScript that is intended to disable the textbox if the admin selects a value from the dropdown.

For some reason, the code I am using is not working because it is not disabling the textbox when a value is selected from the dropdown.

The second task we would like to handle is if the user, for some reason, decides to bypass the dropdown and enter a value into the textbox, we would like some sort of an alert saying something like, "STOP! Please check the dropdown for the value first before entering it into this box"

I tried using Ajax tooltip by grabbing from visual studio's toolbox but there is no tooltip that I can see.

I would greatly appreciate help with these two items but help with any of them is greatly appreciated.

BTW: I already have jQuery library for this JS.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("[id*=ddlWater]").change(function () {
            var row = $(this).closest("tr");
            var value = $(this).val();
            if (value == "" ) {
                row.find("[id*=txt_watersizes]").attr("disabled", "true");
            } else {
                row.find("[id*=txt_watersizes]").removeAttr("disabled");
            }
        });
    });
</script>

     <td>
       <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlWater" AppendDataBoundItems="true" runat="server">
       <asp:ListItem Text="29.9" Value="1" />
       <asp:ListItem Text="2.98" Value="2" />
       <asp:ListItem Text="0.33" Value="3" />      
       </asp:DropDownList>
     </td>
     <td>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txt_watersizes" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    </td>
```

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, that seems like WAY, but WAY too much UI and confusing for the user.

```
You have 2 places to enter a value - combo and text box.
what happens if text box value already exists?
What happens if they change their mind, now want to use combo and not text obx?
```

And you also not only having 2 places for the user to focus on, you also using up valuable space.

I would have a combo box, and then right beside that box, have a button with a "+" or whatever to add. Then you can pop a dialog.

Then:

You don't have to mess with enable/disable.

You have ONE place on the form for users to see/look at the value - not two places.

You don't get users fustrated as to why some box is disabled - they will ask why is this???

So, a simple pop up?

One combo box, one place to choose.

No enable and disable.

And if in the pop up they enter an already existing value, you don't care, since you select that value - but don't add to the combo.

So, say this markup:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="Repeater1_ItemDataBound">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <div style="float: left">
            <h3>First Name</h3>
            <asp:TextBox ID="tFirst" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("FirstName")%>' />
            <h3>Last Name</h3>
            <asp:TextBox ID="tLast" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("LastName") %>' />
        </div>
        <div style="float: left; margin-left: 10px">
            <h3>Hotel</h3>
            <asp:TextBox ID="tHotel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("HotelName") %>' />
        </div>
        <div style="float: left; margin-left: 10px">
            <h3>City</h3>
            <asp:DropDownList ID="cboCity" runat="server" Width="140px" Height="28px"
                DataTextField="City">
            </asp:DropDownList>
            <button id="cmdCboPop" runat="server" class="btn myshadow" style="margin-left: 5px"
                onserverclick="cmdCboPop_ServerClick"
                onclick="if (!popcity(this)) {return false};">
                <span aria-hidden="true" class="glyphicon glyphicon-export"></span>
            </button>
        </div>

        <div style="float: left; margin-left: 10px">
            <h3>Description</h3>
            <asp:TextBox ID="tDescript" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine" Height="160" Width="300"
                Text='<%# Eval("Description") %>' />
        </div>

        <div style="clear: both"></div>
        <hr style="border-top: 2px solid" />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

code to fill is this:

```
    DataTable rstCity = new DataTable();
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
            LoadData();
    }


    void LoadData()
    {
        // load combo in repeater data
        rstCity = General.MyRst("SELECT City FROM City ORDER BY City");

        string strSQL =
            @"SELECT * FROM tblHotelsA WHERE Active = 1
            ORDER BY HotelName";

        Repeater1.DataSource = General.MyRst(strSQL);
        Repeater1.DataBind();
    }

    protected void Repeater1_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
    {
        if ( (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item) ||
              (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)  )

        {
            DropDownList cboCity = e.Item.FindControl("cboCity") as DropDownList;
            cboCity.DataSource = rstCity; cboCity.DataBind();

            cboCity.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("Select City", ""));
            DataRowView rData = e.Item.DataItem as DataRowView;
            Debug.Print(rData["City"].ToString());
            if (rData["City"].ToString() != "")
                cboCity.Text = rData["City"].ToString();

        }
    }
```

Ok, and now we have, see this:

[image]

so, now our code. I used a jQuery.UI dialog.

So, assuming you have jQuery, then you have to add jQuery.UI for the pop dialog.

Note how we have no "funny" kind of enable, or disable. We simple prompt user, and they can cancel or enter new city, and then we add that to the combo list, select it, close the dialog. No enable, no confusing, no 2 different ways, no enable, no disable.

So, the code for above?

This:

```
<div id="mycitypop">
    <h4><i>Enter New City</i></h4>
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtNewCity" runat="server" 
        ClientIDMode="Static" >
    </asp:TextBox>
</div>

<script>
    var okpop = false
    function popcity(btn) {
        if (okpop) {
            okpop = false
            return true
        }    
        $('#txtNewCity').attr('autocomplete', 'off');  
        var mydiv = $("#mycitypop")
        mydiv.dialog({
            modal: true, appendTo: "form",
            title: "New City", closeText: "",
            dialogClass: "dialogWithDropShadow",
            position: { my: 'left top', at: 'right bottom', of: btn },
            buttons: {
                Ok: function () {
                    okpop = true
                    btn.click()
                },
                Cancel: function () {
                    $('#txtNewCity').val("")
                    mydiv.dialog("close")
                }
            }
        });
        return false
    }

</script>
```

And the button click in the repeater, that code to get the current row, add the value is this:

```
    protected void cmdCboPop_ServerClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        HtmlButton btn = (HtmlButton)sender;
        RepeaterItem rRow = (RepeaterItem)btn.NamingContainer;
        // add new row to data base, but only if user entered value
        if (txtNewCity.Text == "")   // exit no user city entered
            return;

        SqlCommand cmdSQL = 
            new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM City WHERE City = @City");
        cmdSQL.Parameters.Add("@City", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = txtNewCity.Text;

        DataTable rstCity = General.MyRstP(cmdSQL);
        if (rstCity.Rows.Count == 0) 
        {
            // we only add a new row not exist (rows = 0)
            DataRow NewRow = rstCity.NewRow();
            NewRow["City"] = txtNewCity.Text;   
            rstCity.Rows.Add(NewRow);
            General.SaveTable(rstCity, "City");
        }           
        // now set cbo Box to this value
        DropDownList cboCity = (DropDownList)rRow.FindControl("cboCity");
        cmdSQL.CommandText = "SELECT City FROM City ORDER BY City";
        cboCity.DataSource = General.MyRstP(cmdSQL);
        cboCity.DataBind();
        cboCity.Items.Insert(1,new ListItem("Select City",""));
        cboCity.Text = txtNewCity.Text;
    }
```

## Edit: Additional code routines used

As noted, I also used those "helper" routines (to save world poverty, and save the keyboard!!!).

That code is this:

```
public static class General
{

public static DataTable MyRst(string strSQL)
{
    DataTable rstData = new DataTable();
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.TEST4))
    {
        using (SqlCommand cmdSQL = new SqlCommand(strSQL, conn))
        {
            cmdSQL.Connection.Open();
            rstData.Load(cmdSQL.ExecuteReader());
        }
    }
    return rstData;
}


    public static DataTable MyRstP(SqlCommand cmdSQL)
    {
        DataTable rstData = new DataTable();
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.TEST4))
        {
            using (cmdSQL)
            {
                cmdSQL.Connection = conn;
                conn.Open();
                rstData.Load(cmdSQL.ExecuteReader());
            }
        }
        return rstData;
    }
```

and

```
    public static void SaveTable(DataTable rstData, string strTable)
    {
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.TEST4))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmdSQL = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM " + strTable, conn))
            {
                SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmdSQL);
                SqlCommandBuilder daU = new SqlCommandBuilder(da);
                conn.Open();
                da.Update(rstData);
            }
        }
    }
```

## edit#3: Full page markup

So, here is the full page markup. Note that I would ONLY cut + paste in the script and css refers right after "title" part, and then of course you can see/use the rest of the markup you have, and then of course our script code at the bottoms/end of the page.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />


    <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


    <style>
        .dialogWithDropShadow {
            box-shadow: 10px 10px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
        }

        .myshadow {
            box-shadow: 8px 8px 8px 0px gray;
            border-radius: 10px;
            border-style: hidden;
            height: 30px
        }

        .myshadow :hover {
            background-color: #789eca;
            transition: 0.5s;
        }
    </style>

</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">


        <h3>Hotels</h3>
        <div style="padding: 35px; width: 65%">

            <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="Repeater1_ItemDataBound">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <div style="float: left">
                        <h3>First Name</h3>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="tFirst" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("FirstName")%>' />
                        <h3>Last Name</h3>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="tLast" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("LastName") %>' />
                    </div>
                    <div style="float: left; margin-left: 10px">
                        <h3>Hotel</h3>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="tHotel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("HotelName") %>' />
                    </div>
                    <div style="float: left; margin-left: 10px">
                        <h3>City</h3>
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="cboCity" runat="server" Width="140px" Height="28px"
                            DataTextField="City">
                        </asp:DropDownList>
                        <button id="cmdCboPop" runat="server" class="btn myshadow" style="margin-left: 5px"
                            onserverclick="cmdCboPop_ServerClick"
                            onclick="if (!popcity(this)) {return false};">
                            <span aria-hidden="true" class="glyphicon glyphicon-export"></span>
                        </button>
                    </div>

                    <div style="float: left; margin-left: 10px">
                        <h3>Description</h3>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="tDescript" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine" Height="160" Width="300"
                            Text='<%# Eval("Description") %>' />
                    </div>

                    <div style="clear: both"></div>
                    <hr style="border-top: 2px solid" />
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:Repeater>
        </div>
        <br />


        <div id="mycitypop">
            <h4><i>Enter New City</i></h4>
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtNewCity" runat="server"
                ClientIDMode="Static">
            </asp:TextBox>
        </div>

        <script>
        var okpop = false
        function popcity(btn) {
            if (okpop) {
                okpop = false
                return true
            }    
            var mydiv = $("#mycitypop")
            mydiv.dialog({
                modal: true, appendTo: "form",
                title: "New City", closeText: "",
                dialogClass: "dialogWithDropShadow",
                position: { my: 'left top', at: 'right bottom', of: btn },
                buttons: {
                    Ok: function () {
                        okpop = true
                        btn.click()
                    },
                    Cancel: function () {
                        $('#txtNewCity').val("")
                        mydiv.dialog("close")
                    }
                }
            });
            return false
        }

    </script>

    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: WOW!!!

Your demo is so neat. A much, much better and more elegant than what I had in mind. WOW.

I am trying to run the code and getting txtNewCity and General.MyRstP(cmdSQL) not declared.

I know I am using something incorrectly.

Thank you very much Albert. This is very advanced

Comment: I will post general.MyRestP. I mean, all it does is save your "keyboard". I "fast" became VERY tired of typing connection's and Sql commands code over and over, right??? So, I just made a general routine to do that for me to save doing that over and over in code. I'll post that code, and the MyRst. (see my edit above in next 5 minutes).

Comment: WOW, thank you so much for sharing. Very kind of you.

I will take me awhile to figure all this out for sure.

Just one curious question, actually two.

1, what is the relationship between City and Hotel in the context you used them on your code? That will help me relate my tables to each  other.

2, Why is repeater not visible? I created dummy data to match yours just so I can some sense of how they work but nothing is getting displayed on the form.

You are truly an MVP, that's for sure.

Comment: @AbertKallal, I have been playing with code you posted here, everything is loading correctly except the New city, this:

~<div id="mycitypop">
    <h4><i>Enter New City</i></h4>
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtNewCity" runat="server" 
        ClientIDMode="Static" >
    </asp:TextBox>
</div>~

I expected it to be hidden until I click the glyphicon icon. The problem is I am not seeing the glyphicon and the newCity div is not hidden.

Am I putting it at the wrong place and secondly, am I using the wrong jQuery UI?

Please help guide me.

Comment: if jQuery.UI is setup correctly, then the div will hide automatic for you.  For glyph icons to show, you have to use a pre bootstrap 4 (there was a law suit, and bootstrap no longer includes glyphicons  by default. You have to use font awesome now. (what a pain). Anyway, I have post all of the markup I used (and I used CDN  for the jquery, juqery.UI, and bootstrap. So, look at my edit3. Note I have included the FULL page markup, and ONLY skipped the very first page directive line, which of course would be different.

Comment: So, with that post, then don't include your bootstrap or jquery, but simple use the CDN ones.  Really not a lot of custom js code in that page. As posted should work.

Comment: Ok, the glyphicon is visible now and I can click the to pop up the New City box.

I will try my luck to see if I can integrate it with the txt_watersizes textbox. I am a database guy and believe in relational, fully normized database. I woud prefer to enter into the txt_watersizes box, have the value stored in our lookup table while the ID gets stored on our main table. If I can't do it, I will use your solution. It is so neat and so elegant.

Thank you for your generosity.  You are truly the nicest guy I have never met.

Comment: In my posted code, I had to "make up" something here. So, I just out of the blue used City with "one simple" Text column. .But, as a general rule, and no doubt in "most" cases, such a ddl would have a PK id (the value field - hidden), and then the text for display field (the City). So, this is just a proof of concept. Without a doubt, with "very" minor changes in the code, one would of course store/retrieve/use/enjoy the PK id from that ddl, and store + use that. However, that's really a "minor" change to the code, and does not reflect, suggest, or even imply that one is limited to text value

Comment: No, sir I am not suggesting that at all. I would be too scared to even go there given your immense skillset. I was just suggesting what I would like to try that approach with what you have given me. Not even sure that I can do but you have provided a blue print (proof of concept).

Thank you very much.